# Buscar y contar cuantas veces se repite una palabra dentro de una tabla mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo un formulario que consta de 40 preguntas en las que se puede responder si o no, busco realizar una consulta para poder mostrar cuantas veces se repite la palabra "si" entre todas las columnas.

Tengo esta consulta en mysql que me regresa las veces que se repite "si" dentro de la columna con el nombre "pregunta_uno" como la podría modificar o cambiar para que en lugar de solo consultar a una columna me consulte a toda la tabla y me muestre cuantas veces se repite:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS si 
FROM tests 
WHERE pregunta_uno = "si";
```

Esto es lo que me retorna esta consulta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon la estructura de la tabla

Comment: listo ya agregue mi tabla

Comment: ¿Te ha servido la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución podría ser un consulta de este tipo:

```
SELECT
  id_usu,
  if(pregunta_1='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_2='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_3='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_4='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_5='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_6='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_7='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_8='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_9='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_10='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_11='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_12='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_13='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_14='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_15='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_16='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_17='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_18='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_19='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_20='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_21='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_22='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_23='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_24='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_25='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_26='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_27='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_28='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_29='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_30='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_31='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_32='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_33='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_34='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_35='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_36='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_37='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_38='si',1,0) +
  if(pregunta_39='si',1,0) + 
  if(pregunta_40='si',1,0) AS total_si
FROM
  preguntas;
```

Te dejo el ejemplo en http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/874b59/16